# Render React JSX template page: error unexpected < token

Tags: reactjs, jsx, viewengine

I am using `React` for my main app that is started after user logs in. Before user logs in I have several pages (log in, sign up, error, reset password) that are outside of the main app. For the main app I set the view engine to be:

```
app.engine('jsx', require('express-react-views').createEngine());
```

So, `jsx` view engine is now set. Right now I want to have several templates for the pages that I have (log in, error, etc.) and I want to inject them with values. I tried using `jsx` but somehow it is not working, and I do not know why. For instance, here is my `error.jsx`:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');

class ErrorPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Error</title>
        </head>
        <div>
          {this.props.error_message}
        </div>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ErrorPage;
```

I want to inject it with `error_message` like this:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  //res.locals.message = err.message;
  //res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  var path = __dirname + '/public/error.jsx';
  //res.sendFile(path);
  res.render(path, {
    error_message: err.message 
  });
});
```

Right now it is not working giving me

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

How could I either use `jsx` for sending separate templates or use another view template side by side? I tried using `handlebars`, but I am not sure how I can make multiple view engines work at the same time. It would be better though to just accommodate `jsx` for the purpose. My main `React` app is working because I attach it to a `DOM` root element and using `webpack configs`, but here I can not do this: I want to send a template and just inject a bunch of parameters there.

Comment: Can you include your error page here? I think that's causing the issue

Comment: I included it: the `jsx` template, that is it, and that is what I want to do. `jsx` template is already having `html` tags

Comment: I mean put it in this post I want to see if there are issues there

Comment: I put it already. I do not have anything else. Look at the top `error.jsx`

Comment: I guess, you need to parse your jsx file before using it, can you try once transpile your jsx to js then use it

Comment: I do not know how to do that